# why such a point exists?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given oval $$O: \frac{x^2}6+\frac{y^2}3=1$$ and point $A (2,1)$ on it, draw two lines $l_1$, $l_2$ passing through  $A$ s.t. the slopes satisfy $k_1k_2=2$, let $l_1$ and $l_2$ intersect with $O$ at $B$ and $C$, then line $BC$ always pass point $D(\frac{10}3, -\frac{5}3)$.

My question is, why such a point $D$ exists? what's the relationship between $A$ and $D$?

Comment: I believe you mean to say that the lines pass through $A$, yes? 

What do you mean by "why"? It is not clear what you expect as an answer.

Comment: Each of the lines meets O at two points. How are you choosing B and C?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Each of the lines meets $O$ at the point $A$ and at another point. $B$ and $C$ are the points that aren't $A$.

Comment: This does not hold in general when the lines have negative slopes. Consider the lines $y=-2x+5$ and $y=-x+3$ for example, which satisfy the constraint yet fail to behave as you stated.

Comment: @Allawonder tanks pointing this out

Comment: FYI, $D$ is given by $$\left(\frac{-p(b^2+a^2k_1k_2)}{b^2-a^2k_1k_2},\frac{q(b^2+a^2k_1k_2)}{b^2-a^2k_1k_2}\right)$$where $A(p,q)$ is a point on $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $O$ be an ellipse, and fix some $D \notin O$.

Then there is a natural involution $i_D : O \to O$ from the ellipse to itself where a point $P \in O$ is sent to the other intersection point of $(DP)$ with $O$. Furthermore, this involution is algebraic : the coordinates of $i_D(P)$ are some quotient of polynomials in terms of the coordinates of $P$.

Then, fix some $A \in O$ and let $s_A : O \to \Bbb P^1(\Bbb R) = \Bbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ be the function  mapping a point $P$ to the slope of $(AP)$. This is also an algebraic map.

Finally let $h(s) = 2/s$ be the automorphism of $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb R)$ that you're looking at.

If you pick two random points $B_1,B_2$ on $O$, your construction sends them to $C_1,C_2$ where $C_i = s_A^{-1} \circ h \circ s_A (B_i)$. Then, if you take $D$ to be the intersection of $(B_1C_1)$ and $(B_2C_2)$ then $i_D \circ s_A^{-1} \circ h \circ s_A$ is an automorphism of $O$ that has at least four fixed points.

Or rather, $s_A \circ i_D \circ s_A^{-1} \circ h$ is an automorphism of $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb R)$ that has at least four fixed points.

But what can this algebraic map be ? Since it's algebraic it's a map $F : s \mapsto f(s)/g(s)$ where $f,g$ are polynomials. Moreover since it is injective, $f$ and $g$ must have degree at most $1$, so $F(s)$ has the form $(as+b)/(cs+d)$.

Then $F(s)-s = (-cs^2+(a-d)s+b) / (cs+d)$ and this has at least four zeroes. But its numerator only has degree $2$, so $F(s)-s$ must be identically zero, which means that $s_A \circ i_D \circ s_A^{-1} \circ h$ (and $i_D \circ s_A^{-1} \circ h \circ s_A$) are the identity.

---

Or if you want to say all this really concisely, an ellipse is a genus $0$ curve (like $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb R)$) and so its automorphisms are determined by the images of $3$ points. Since $i_D$ and $s_A^{-1} \circ h \circ s_A$ agree on $4$ points, they must match completely.

Comment: I feel this is the answer though can’t understand it, thx!

Comment: I was thinking that your question about "the relationship between $A$ and $D$" could be interesting but then I realized that for any $D \notin O$ and any $A \in O$ there is a corresponding transformation on the slopes that make it work, so there isn't really a relationship between $A$ and $D$.

Comment: I guess $A$ and $D$ are linked via the const $k_1 k_2$.

Answer (score 2):

We can scale the problem by taking $y\to y\sqrt{2}$. Then

$$A \to (2,\sqrt{2}),$$

$$O \to x^2+y^2=6,$$

and the condition that $k_1k_2=2$ is replaced by the condition that $k_1k_2=4$.

We claim the following:

> Let $A$ be a point on circle $\Omega$ centered at point $O$, let $P$ be the reflection of $A$ about the $x$-axis, and let $t$ be a real number. Let $Q$ be the second intersection of the line through $A$ with slope $t$ with $\Omega$, and let $B$ and $C$ be points on $O$ such that the slopes of lines $AB$ and $AC$ multiply to $t^2$. Then lines $OP$, $BC$, and the tangent to $\Omega$ at $Q$ concur.

This shouldn't be too hard to prove, though I don't see how to do it immediately. But, to answer your second question ("What's the relationship between $A$ and $D$?), $D$ is the intersection between the line $OP$ (the reflection of line $OA$ across the $x$-axis) and the tangent line that the line $BC$ tends to when $B\to C$.

Once can see that this should be what $D$ is, if $D$ does indeed exist, because the line $OP$ is what $BC$ tends to when one of ($AB$, $AC$) has slope $\epsilon$ and the other has slope $t^2/\epsilon$ (one line tends to vertical and the other tends towards horizontal), while the tangent at $Q$ to $\Omega$ is what $BC$ tends to when $B\to C$.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why this is not useful?

Comment: Than you. I like mercio’s answer. He explains why there exists a $D$ for all possible $BC$, from a higher point of view (alas too high for me now). This answer rather explains “assume there is a $D$, what’s the quickest way to locate it — by 2 extreme cases”

Answer (score 2):

This fact is true for any point $A$ of the ellipse and any other value for the constant $2$.

For every point $B$, the maps
$$ point(B) \mapsto line(AB) \mapsto line(AC) \mapsto point(C) $$
are projective, so their composition $B\mapsto C$ is a projective transform from the ellipse to itself. Moreover, $C$ is mapped back to $B$, so this transform is an involution.

Involutions are always projections from a certain point which is $D$ in our case.

Comment: Involutions are always projections from a certain point — may I ask why? It’s not obvious to me. Maybe I got it wrong, but a spinning don’t have such certain point, no?

Comment: Suppose that two points, $B_1$ and $B_2$ are mapped to $C_1$ and $C_2$, resp., and let $D=B_1C_1\cap B_2C_2$. The perspectivity through $D$ maps $B_i$ to $C_i$ and back. The images of 3 points determine the projective transform.

Comment: need prove $B_3C_3$ also pass thru $D$

Comment: $B_3=C_1$ and $C_3=B_1$. :-///